# Using Dynamics AX's Business Conectors to Generate Sales Orders

Tags: visual-studio-2008, interop, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

So, just like the title says, I need to create an application that gets data from another Database, and shoves it through Dynamics AX's throat.

This data comes from a portal, not Enterprise Portal, but a PHP one. It stores some data from the order in a separate database. So as said, I need  to 'import' that to AX, creating the sales orders with the data I have from the other database.

Also I'd like some references on Business Conector too, does it handle all those RECIDS and references that AX uses for me?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

OK, I'm able to insert records in AX's database, theres just one problem. I can't generate the internal ID. Like, the 'AccountNum' field for the CustTable. Is there a way to capture it from business connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I didn't use the .NET Business Connector, we got the other application to insert data in a table in the AX's database. Then found some code on the internet to generate the next salesID for each record I inserted in the SalesTable table. Though I must add that using the .NET Business Connector didn't sound so hard from what I've searched.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the AXSalesTable and AXSalesLine classes from your application. These will take care of a lot of the housekeeping, also automatically creation of sales id's.

Business Connector documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496526.aspx